# IP Header of two packets received are displayed differently

Tags: c, network-programming, ip

I have the following code:

```
struct ip_header {
    unsigned char ip_hl:4;  /* header length 4 bits*/
    unsigned char ip_ver:4; /* version 4 bits*/ 
    unsigned char ip_dscp:6;/* dscp (previously part of type of service) 6 bits*/
    unsigned char ip_ecn:2; /* ecn (previously part of type of service) 2 bits*/
    unsigned int ip_len:16;  /* total length 2 bytes*/
    unsigned int ip_id:16;  /* identification 2 bytes*/
    unsigned char ip_rf:1;  /* reserved fragment flag */
    unsigned char ip_df:1;  /* dont fragment flag */
    unsigned char ip_mf:1;  /* more fragments flag */
    unsigned int ip_off:13; /* fragment offset */
    unsigned int ip_ttl:8;  /* time to live */
    unsigned int ip_p:8;    /* protocol */
    unsigned int ip_sum:16; /* checksum */
    unsigned char ip_src[4];/* source address */
    unsigned char ip_dst[4];/* dest */
};
...
    void decode_ip(const unsigned char *header_start) {
        int i;

    const struct ip_header *ip_hdr;

    ip_hdr = (const struct ip_header *)(header_start + ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE);


    printf("\tIP Reserved Flag  : %u\n", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_rf);  
    printf("\tIP Dont Fragment  : %u\n", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_df);  
    printf("\tIP More Fragments : %u\n", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_mf);  
    printf("\tIP Offset         : %u\n", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_off); 
    printf("\tIP Source         : %u", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_src[0]);
    for (i=1;i<4; i++) printf(".%u", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_src[i]);
    printf("\n\tIP Destination    : %u", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_dst[0]);  
    for (i=1;i<4; i++) printf(".%u", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_dst[i]);   
}
```

Here is the output of the code:

[image]

You can notice that the bootom packet is fine, but the top one is not. FOr instance All flags are 0, but fragmentation offset is 8, then IP source and IP destination are mixed up.#

Can someone tell me what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the RFC ([See the wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)):

*For fragmented packets, all fragments except the last have the MF flag set. The last fragment has a non-zero Fragment Offset field, differentiating it from an unfragmented packet.*

What you're likely seeing here is the last packet of a fragmented set.

In regards the mixed up IPs: They look fine to me - One packet is going one way and the other packet going the other.

Comment: Are you suggesting that my `struct ip_header` is one bit shifted for all packets except the last one?

Comment: No. There is nothing wrong with it at all. It is working as intended.